# Where can I get longitudinal data of the COVID-19 cases?

Tags: covid-19, statistics, coronavirus

Where can I download a full dataset of the SARS-CoV-2 pandemics containing time information for each individual (date of infection, date of death, age, gender, weight, censoring information...)

It's important to get this information in order to do survival analyses and other studies.

I'm only able to find aggregated data. For example this Chinese dataset.
https://github.com/BlankerL/DXY-COVID-19-Data

Comment: possible duplicate of https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21477/how-extensive-is-the-us-govt-machine-readable-dataset-on-covid-19 or https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21279/where-to-find-a-database-containing-covid-19-information/21666#21666 Have you looked at the previous questions?

Comment: Check the tag `covid-19-datasets` first to see if the answer is there.

Comment: @Graham that databases don't contain time information on a per individual basis.

Comment: Have you checked out `worldometers` yet? Not as detailed a data set as you seek but it updates by the minute.

Comment: None of those sources provide detailed information of each individual through time  (date of infection, date of discharge, date of death, age, gender, weight, blood type, treatment...)